# "firebase" is not defined in generator-gulp-angular

Tags: angularjs, firebase, generator-gulp-angular

I am using `generator-gulp-angular`
I added firebase and angularfire with

```
bower install firebase --save
bower install angularfire --save
```

Then I added firebase in the module as below.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['firebase']
```

Then in the MainController, I defined config and initialized as below.

```
vm.config = {
       apiKey: "yuygjgjhghjguyfuyfuyccncvcn",
       authDomain: "hjgjhghjghjg.firebaseapp.com",
       databaseURL: "https://hjghjgjhghj.firebaseio.com"
    }; 

function activate() {
      getWebDevTec();
      getMenu();
      firebase.initializeApp(vm.config);
      $timeout(function() {
        vm.classAnimation = 'rubberBand';
      }, 4000);
    }
```

When I do `gulp serve`, But I am getting below error.

```
  29:7    error  "firebase" is not defined                 no-undef
```

Could you please suggest where I am going wrong.

Comment: You `bower install`'d, but did you include the `<script>` tags in your HTML?

Comment: @SteamDev, when I installed with bower, it added the script tags in /tmp/serve/index.html.                                                                                                   <script src="../bower_components/firebase/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angularfire/dist/angularfire.js"></script>.  Do we need to add them elsewhere also?

Comment: Are you injecting the `firebase` service into your controller?

Comment: Ahhh...forgot to inject it. Thank you @SteamDev. If you can add it as answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you inject the `firebase` service into your controller